# How to compile Java code online?

Tags: java, javascript, html, compiler-construction

Making a site, comparing the performance of lambda expressions in Java 8 vs. Non-lambda expressions, using html and javascript. Got most of the site done, right now the example code gets displayed by using iframes that display the .java files, then I embedded java applets that run the .class files. What I'm not sure how to do is, how can I display the code in pre tags for example and then compile the code online? That way the user can modify source code to test different stuff such as stream() vs parallelStream().

Comment: The difference between stream() and parallelStream() depends on the hardware you are using.  You can compile the code on your server, but if you are running it on the client machine, the results will depend on what machine that is.

Comment: My question would then be, how can I compile on my server? Just finished my 1st year of University and we don't learn web development until next year. All the html and javascript I know, I tought myself off youtube

Comment: Your browser sends the Java to the server as a request, which it saves in a file and the server runs `javac` to compile it and if successful, you can tell the browser to run an applet which uses the code on the server you just compiled.

Comment: Got a link to a tutorial???

Comment: If you are letting users enter in code to compile and run on your server there are some huge security problems you need to consider. I can't tell from your question if you are letting users change the code or not though, so you might not have anything to consider.

Comment: Would like the code in the .java file to be displayed in a textarea, the if the user wishes to edit it they may, then the code is compiled online (which I still can't figure out how to do) and then the .class file is run by an applet

Comment: You would need a whole series of tutorials. I suggest you try doing this one task at a time. I assume you want something like this http://ideone.com/ or http://kotlin-demo.jetbrains.com/

Comment: sort of, just need a way for the code to be compiled, everything else is set up, just need a way to compile the code

Answer (score 0):

What sort of code are you trying to put into a webpage? Usually when people try to embed java applets they use the applet tag for html.

```
<applet code="YourMainClass.class" archive="YourApplet.jar" width="800" height="600">
</applet>
```

Please correct me if I'm getting the wrong idea of what you are trying to achieve, but are you just trying to embed a java applet into a website? Or are you literally trying to compile code online?

Comment: The applet tag is not supported in HTML 5.

Comment: I have an applet for the lambda expression and for the none lambda expression, here is the one for non-lambda expression <applet id="nlApplet" code="Blank.class" width="300" height="200"></applet>, starts by loading a blank screen then opens other .class files later that output test results

Comment: Want to compile code from a pre tag or text area into the .class file to be run by the applet

Comment: @Creator13 I did not know that they removed the applet tag, i don't really use it too much but it seems like a shame because that seems relatively simple compared to the new methods of adding an applet.

Comment: @AdamCU I dont think what you are trying to do can be done easily, you would need a java compiler such as Javac being run to compile the code and probably a server with some other code to handle this.